# How to change highlighted navitem when change pages. Next.js + React + Tailwind + tailwindui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css

Sorry about the rusty English, it's my first time here ! Also my first Next.js project.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
  "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
  "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
  "next": "13.4.7",
  "postcss": "8.4.24",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
}
```

I have a project in Next.js. The project is like this:

[image: Project tree]

So inside the archive, `Navbar.js`, the code is like this:

```
'use client';

import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import { Bars3Icon, BellIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', href: '#', current: true },
  { name: 'Team', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Projects', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Calendar', href: '#', current: false },
];

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <Disclosure as='nav' className='bg-white shadow-md'>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className='mx-auto w-full px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8'>
            <div className='relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between'>
              <div className='absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden'>
                {/* Mobile menu button*/}
                <Disclosure.Button className='inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white'>
                  <span className='sr-only'>Open main menu</span>
                  {open ? (
                    <XMarkIcon className='block h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                  ) : (
                    <Bars3Icon className='block h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                  )}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>
              <div className='flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start'>
                <div className='flex flex-shrink-0 items-center'>
                  <img
                    className='block h-8 w-auto lg:hidden'
                    src='https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500'
                    alt='Your Company'
                  />
                  <img
                    className='hidden h-8 w-auto lg:block'
                    src='https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500'
                    alt='Your Company'
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block'>
                  <div className='flex space-x-4'>
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <a
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className={classNames(
                          item.current
                            ? 'text-orange-500 border-b-2 border-orange-500'
                            : 'text-gray-300 hover:border-b-2 hover:border-orange-300 hover:text-orange-300',
                          'rounded-sm px-3 py-5 text-sm font-medium'
                        )}
                        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0'>
                {/* Profile dropdown */}
                <Menu as='div' className='relative ml-3'>
                  <div>
                    <Menu.Button className='flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800'>
                      <span className='sr-only'>Open user menu</span>
                      <img
                        className='h-8 w-8 rounded-full'
                        src='/images/me.jpeg'
                        alt='photo'
                      />
                    </Menu.Button>
                  </div>
                  <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter='transition ease-out duration-100'
                    enterFrom='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                    enterTo='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                    leave='transition ease-in duration-75'
                    leaveFrom='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                    leaveTo='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                  >
                    <Menu.Items className='absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none'>
                      <Menu.Item>
                        {({ active }) => (
                          <a
                            href='#'
                            className={classNames(
                              active ? 'bg-orange-500' : '',
                              'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-black sm:text-white '
                            )}
                          >
                            Hi ! Nice to meet you!
                          </a>
                        )}
                      </Menu.Item>
                    </Menu.Items>
                  </Transition>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Disclosure.Panel className='sm:hidden'>
            <div className='space-y-1 px-2 pb-3 pt-2'>
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <Disclosure.Button
                  key={item.name}
                  as='a'
                  href={item.href}
                  className={classNames(
                    item.current
                      ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
                      : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                    'block rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-base font-medium'
                  )}
                  aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  );
}
```

The `layout.js` of projects:

```
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

export default function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}) {
  return (
    <section>
      <Navbar />

      {children}
    </section>
  );
}
```

So I want to change the color of the active item of the navbar when you click on the page that you want to go.

I am trying to change the state of the property (current) of the `navItem`, but I don't know how. I just want to know in what page I am.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the useState, to maintain the state of the navItems, than use a function handleClick to update the value of the 'current'.

The code:

```
'use client';

import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { useState } from 'react';

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/', current: true },
  { name: 'Projects', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Calendar', href: '#', current: false },
];

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ');
}

export default function Navbar() {
  const [navItems, setNavItems] = useState(navigation);

  const handleItemClick = (index) => {
    const updatedNavItems = navItems.map((item, i) => ({
      ...item,
      current: i === index,
    }));
    setNavItems(updatedNavItems);
  };

  return (
    <Disclosure as='nav' className='bg-white shadow-md'>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className='mx-auto w-full px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8'>
            <div className='relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between'>
              <div className='absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden'>
                {/* Mobile menu button*/}
                <Disclosure.Button className='inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white'>
                  <span className='sr-only'>Open main menu</span>
                  {open ? (
                    <XMarkIcon className='block h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                  ) : (
                    <Bars3Icon className='block h-6 w-6' aria-hidden='true' />
                  )}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>
              <div className='flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start'>
                <div className='flex flex-shrink-0 items-center'>
                  <img
                    className='block h-8 w-auto lg:hidden'
                    src='https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500'
                    alt='Your Company'
                  />
                  <img
                    className='hidden h-8 w-auto lg:block'
                    src='https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500'
                    alt='Your Company'
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block'>
                  <div className='flex space-x-4'>
                    {navItems.map((item, index) => (
                      <a
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className={classNames(
                          item.current
                            ? 'text-orange-500 border-b-2 border-orange-500'
                            : 'text-gray-300 hover:border-b-2 hover:border-orange-300 hover:text-orange-300',
                          'rounded-sm px-3 py-5 text-sm font-medium'
                        )}
                        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                        onClick={() => handleItemClick(index)}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0'>
                {/* Profile dropdown */}
                <Menu as='div' className='relative ml-3'>
                  <div>
                    <Menu.Button className='flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800'>
                      <span className='sr-only'>Open user menu</span>
                      <img
                        className='h-8 w-8 rounded-full'
                        src='/images/me.jpeg'
                        alt='photo'
                      />
                    </Menu.Button>
                  </div>
                  <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter='transition ease-out duration-100'
                    enterFrom='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                    enterTo='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                    leave='transition ease-in duration-75'
                    leaveFrom='transform opacity-100 scale-100'
                    leaveTo='transform opacity-0 scale-95'
                  >
                    <Menu.Items className='absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none'>
                      <Menu.Item>
                        {({ active }) => (
                          <a
                            href='#'
                            className={classNames(
                              active ? 'bg-orange-500' : '',
                              'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-black sm:text-white '
                            )}
                          >
                            Hi ! Nice to meet you!
                          </a>
                        )}
                      </Menu.Item>
                    </Menu.Items>
                  </Transition>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Disclosure.Panel className='sm:hidden'>
            <div className='space-y-1 px-2 pb-3 pt-2'>
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <Disclosure.Button
                  key={item.name}
                  as='a'
                  href={item.href}
                  className={classNames(
                    item.current
                      ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white'
                      : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                    'block rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-base font-medium'
                  )}
                  aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  );
}
```